# Передача параметров через Intent

Tags: android

Мне надо передать объект через Intent, нашел [статью](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-activity.html), как это сделать, но чет не получается передать putExtra -ом.

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Сериализовать объект? Или его восстановить из парселя?

Comment: да я чего-то не догоняю...
имплементировал своему обьекту парсель, а че дальше с ним делать? теперь его можно передавать putExtra ?

Answer (score 2):

В методе `writeToParcel` сериализуете все поля объекта, как это указано в статье. А в конструкторе, принимающем `Parcel` десериализуете.
В интенте передавать через `intent.putParcelableExtra(key, object)`, а забирать через `intent.getExtra(key)`.

Answer (score 2):

Еще как вариант можно сделать объекты, которые нужно передавать в интенте как `Serializable`. Добавлять их в extras интента можно через `putExtra()`, а извлекать через `intent.getSerializableExtra()` с приведением результата к нужному типу. Мы в текущем проекте используем такой подходи все работает нормально. Объекты у нас достаточно сложные. Главный момент - все составные части объекта тоже должны быть `Serializable`